# Does Android View.postDelayed leak reference?

Tags: android, view, handler

I wonder if runnable passed to `View.postDelayed` will be automatically removed when the view is detached from the parent.

I looked in the source of the `View` class and it is posted to some `Handler` that it gets outside. But life cycle of that handler is not clear.

Does anyone know the answer?

Comment: I suppose you could test this by putting a very long delay and destroying the activity.

Comment: yes, it will leak, cannot you use `View#removeCallbacks` ?

Comment: This is the option, but I was thinking might be Android is clever to remove it itself

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I wonder if runnable passed to View.postDelayed will be automatically
> removed when the view is detached from the parent.

It will after the run method finishes to execute. If you have a infinite loop into it, it will never be removed and, therefore, you will leak the view, and the Activity that uses that view.

Comment: Let's assume it is not loop but delay interval is big. Since it is not executed yet it keeps all references also

Comment: the same applies in this case. You will leak memory until the delay exipers and the runnable executed. Only then all the resources can be freed

Comment: It's too bad that view doesn't `clearCallbacks` on detach